# Center a div in a section

Tags: css, margin, centering

I'm trying to center a `<div>` in `<section>`. Setting margin-left and margin-right to `auto` isn't working (my usual method). What am I forgetting?

jsFiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/veWKh/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/veWKh/3/ - `text-align: center` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting the width, otherwise the div is display block and has a width of 100%: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/veWKh/1/

CSS:

```
section {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

div {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Display inline-block, than you will need a text-align: center. because it's handled as inline.

Answer (score 2):

For `margin:auto` to work you need to give the `div` a set `width` eg:

```
div {
    width:100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
section {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

div {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the width first.Other wise it will occupy the full space and setting margins will not work

```
div {
    width:30em; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This width of your div is not limited so what you are doing is not visible.

```
div {
    display:block;
    width:50%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly:

```
section
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

This will make everything centered, though. Otherwise you can just do this:

```
div 
{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    margin: auto;
}
```